# Getting current time of day down to milliseconds error

Tags: ios, swift, time

I have been attempting to access the time of day in hour:minute:second format however all that these

```
    println(CFTimeZoneCopySystem())
    println(CFTimeZoneCopyDefault())
    println(gettimeofday)
    println(CACurrentMediaTime)
```

print are

```
America/New_York (EDT) offset -14400 (Daylight)
America/New_York (EDT) offset -14400 (Daylight)
(Function)
(Function)
```

I don't understand why these are simply printing out "(function)" and I am also unsure as to what time format 14400 is.  I want to be able to access something that would be accurate across bluetooth devices. so that is why I would prefer to access milliseconds.  I know there was another question similar to this one however I do not think they received this article as well as I do not understand objective-C

Comment: offset of -14400 is the timezone (4 hours)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the code below:

```
let formatter = NSDateFormatter()
//formatter.timeZone = NSTimeZone(forSecondsFromGMT: 0)  // you can set GMT time
formatter.timeZone = NSTimeZone.localTimeZone() // or as local time
formatter.dateFormat = "HH:mm:ss.SSS"
println(formatter.stringFromDate(NSDate()))
```

**Output**: "05:57:26.123"